# Find permutations ASCII conversion

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem set and I can't figure out how this function is working. Any help would be much appreciated. Mainly i'm confused on why it is using ASCII with the '0' and what the incrementing and decrementing is achieving after they cast to ascii.. is it shifting counts?

```
bool isPermutation(string str1, string str2)
{
    if(str1.size() != str2.size())
        return false;

    int i, j, counts[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 10;i++)
        counts[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
        counts[str1[i] - '0']++; // (1)

    for(i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
        counts[str2[i] - '0']--; // (2)

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) // (3)
        if(counts[i] != 0) // (4)
            return true; // (5) Should be return false;

    return false; // (6) Should be return true;
}
```

Comment: 0 is zero but `'0' == 48`. Take a look here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I don't understand; which is the function you're wondering about? What is to be considered as code, the actual code above or the comments?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is incorrect. The most critical error is that the array `counts` is too small as I mentioned in my comment. Let me update the program a bit to the following:

```
bool isPermutation(std::string a, std::string b) {
    char counts[256] = {0}; // initializes all elements to zero.

    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    for (int i; i < a.size(); ++i)
        counts[a[i]]++;

    for (int i; i < b.size(); ++i)
        counts[b[i]]--;

    for (int i; i < sizeof(counts) / sizeof(counts[0]); ++i)
        if (counts[i] != 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

The whole idea is to count the number of instances of each character in `a`; so when the first `for`-loop is finished, `counts[i]` contains the number of instances (value) of each letter (index, ASCII-valued).

Then you decrement it in the second `for`-loop. And of these don't match, i.e., all of `counts` is not zero, then it cannot be a permutation.